# How do I search source files for certain strings using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a PHP developer, and was just asked to develop a web app in .NET.  With PHP, I use Sublime Text 3, which allows you to search for a sting in a particular folder by right-clicking the folder name and clicking on "Find in Folder."  That displays a Find Results page with all instances of that string in that folder.

Is there any such feature in .NET?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not a feature of .NET any more than it's a feature of PHP - what IDE are you using to write your C# code? If you're using Sublimt Text 3 you can do it the same way as before. If you're using Visual Studio, Ctrl-Shift-F is what you want (Find in Files). (On the other hand, if you're trying to find what calls another method etc, there are much better ways of doing it...)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET or PHP...

Comment: Thanks to all!  Ctrl+Shift+F did it.

Comment: Dusan - I am using Visual Studio 2013 for this app, so it does pertain to ASP.NET.

Comment: That is quite a task you took on if you have no experience with ,Net. Good luck with it. @DourHighArch and Dusan, that's not entirely true. This is a question about a specific feature of "software tools commonly used by programmers" which is on-topic. OP is used to Sublime Text, and now switching to .NET/Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! I developed apps in VB 6 several years ago, before moving to PHP, but there is the learning curve. I appreciate it!

Comment: @wilcan, you may want to [edit] the title of your post to something like "How do I search source files for certain strings using Visual Studio?", to make it clearer (and prevent more close votes). And some of the content of your question as well along those lines

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Visual Studio try Ctrl+Shift+F to Find in Files

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search all (code) files in a folder for a particular text?

It does not matter, whether it is PHP or C#, you could still use Sublime or any other editor that has your feature.

If you want that feature in the IDE you are programming, that would probably be VisualStudio when you code in C#. There are two possibilities:

- If you want to search in the code of the current Solution, use "Find in Files" (Ctrl-Shift-F) and select "Entire Solution" or "Current Project" under "Look in".
- If you want to search any files, not necessarily referenced in the solution, use "Find in Files" but choose your path using the ellipses next to the "Look In" drop down box, or type in the path.